# T-SQL GRANT as Column Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I making a project. I'm using T-SQL. I want to do this;

```
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE FROM dbo.ogrenciler(where dbo_ogrenci.b_id = 2) TO dekan;
```

I tried;

```
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE FROM dbo.ogrenciler WHERE dbo_ogrenci.b_id = 2 TO dekan;
```

Actually didn't work. How can i express this? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You probably want to start here: ["Row-Level Security"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: The phrase "doesn't work" is NEVER a good thing to post. You encountered an error - post the complete error. But first, look at the syntax for [grant statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). No one needs to correct basic syntax errors for you.